# react-router-dom giving 404 on multiple / in url

Tags: react-router-dom

React router dom is throwing 404 on `/blogs/new`
But it works fine if i remove the second url like `/blogs` or any other single `/` url

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import HomePage from './HomePage';
import Blogs from './Blogs';
import NewBlog from './NewBlog';

const Main = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/blogs' component={Blogs} />
                <Route path='/blogs/new' component={NewBlog} />
                <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
};

export default Main;
```

Comment: Na man, not working here

Comment: Did it work out?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written seems fine. I tried a simple example on code sandbox with react-router-dom and seems to be working just as expected. You can check this out below and see if you are making some typo somewhere in your code -

[image: Edit React Router (forked)]

It's probably possible that you are making some typo in writing your URLs in either the code or the browser because code-wise it seems correct to me.

Comment: @HrithikNaha Check the *edit on CodeSandbox*. Its same as your code and it works

Comment: Yes, ive checked it. And i know it should work. But what can i do. JS is unpredictable.

Comment: @HrithikNaha Nope. Js works just as expected. Your codebase must have some error elsewhere. Maybe something in your *App.js* or elsewhere. I have been using react-router for quite a while now...didn't have this issue anytime

Comment: Do you use CRA?

Comment: @HrithikNaha create-react-app? Yes